# Undefined Method for Active Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When creating a new job, I get an error about an undefined method `Employee`. I will post relevant sections of my code; thanks in advance for the help!

Here is the error message:

> undefined method `employee' for #
>   ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []

`_form.html.erb` (where error is occuring):

```
  <td colspan="4">Client-Job
          # <%= text_field_tag 'client_num', @job.opportunities.employee.office.client_num, :size => "4", :readonly => true, :tabindex => -1 %>
          -<%= f.text_field :number %></td>
```

**Jobs Controller:**

```
class JobsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_job, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  skip_load_and_authorize_resource
  # GET /jobs
  # GET /jobs.json
  def index
    @jobs = Job.all
  end

  # GET /jobs/1
  # GET /jobs/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /jobs/new
  def new
    @job = Job.new
  end

  # GET /jobs/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /jobs
  # POST /jobs.json
  def create
    @job = Job.new(job_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @job.save
        format.html { redirect_to @job, notice: 'Job was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @job }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @job.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /jobs/1
  # PATCH/PUT /jobs/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @job.update(job_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @job, notice: 'Job was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @job }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @job.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /jobs/1
  # DELETE /jobs/1.json
  def destroy
    @job.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to jobs_url, notice: 'Job was successfully deleted.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private

  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_job
    @job = Job.find(params[:id])
  end

  # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
  def job_params
    params.require(:job).permit(:opportunity_id, :number, :name, :flight_date, :flight_sub, :camera, :roll, :map_type, :plan_only, :lab_only, :est_hrs_model, :due_date, :edge_job_id, :custom_trans, :comp_inhouse, :delivered_date, :done, :control_in, :control_status, :at_date, :control_results, :control_check, :scan_staff, :scan_date, :scan_check, :comp_staff, :comp_date, :comp_check, :comp_sub, :comp_sub_due_date, :comp_sub_rec, :img_staff, :img_date, :img_check, :edit_staff, :edit_date, :edit_check, :notes, :file1, :file2, :file3, :file4, :file5, :add_files)
  end
end
```

**Employee Controller:**

```
class EmployeesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_employee, only: :show
  skip_load_and_authorize_resource

  # GET /employees
  # GET /employees.json
  def index
    @employees = Employee.all
  end

  # GET /employees/1
  # GET /employees/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /employees/new
  def new
    @employee = Employee.new
  end

  # GET /employees/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /employees
  # POST /employees.json
  def create
    @employee = Employee.new(employee_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @employee.save
        format.html { redirect_to @employee, notice: 'Contact was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @employee }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @employee.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /employees/1
  # PATCH/PUT /employees/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @employee.update(employee_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @employee, notice: 'Contact was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @employee }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @employee.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /employees/1
  # DELETE /employees/1.json
  def destroy
    @employee.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to employees_url, notice: 'Contact was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private

  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_employee
    @employee = Employee.find(params[:id])
    @opportunities = @employee.opportunities.all
  end

  # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
  def employee_params
    params.require(:employee).permit(:office_id, :f_name, :l_name, :suffix, :position, :email, :phone, :ext, :mobile, :per_email, :per_phone, :archived, :replacement)
  end
end
```

**Job Model:**

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :file1, AttachmentUploader
  belongs_to :cost_proposal
  has_many :opportunities
end
```

**Employee Model:**

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :office
  has_many :opportunities
  has_one :user
  delegate :company, to: :office
  validates :f_name, :l_name, presence: true

  def self.emp_id(emp_id)
    find_by(id: emp_id)
  end

  def self.emp_f_name(emp_id)
    find_by(id: emp_id).f_name
  end

  def name_1
    [f_name, l_name].compact.join(' ')
  end

  def full_name
    if suffix?
      [name_1, suffix].compact.join(', ')
    else
      name_1
    end
  end

  def self.emp_full_name(emp_id)
    find_by(id: emp_id).full_name
  end

  def full_phone
    if ext?
      [phone, ext].compact.join(' ext: ')
    else
      phone
    end
  end
end
```

**Schema.rb:**(relevant tables)

```
  create_table 'employees', force: true do |t|
    t.integer  'office_id'
    t.string   'f_name'
    t.string   'l_name'
    t.string   'suffix'
    t.string   'email'
    t.string   'phone'
    t.string   'ext'
    t.string   'mobile'
    t.string   'per_email'
    t.string   'per_phone'
    t.integer  'archived'
    t.integer  'replacement'
    t.datetime 'created_at'
    t.datetime 'updated_at'
    t.string   'position'
  end

  create_table 'jobs', force: true do |t|
    t.integer  'cost_proposal_id'
    t.string   'number'
    t.string   'name'
    t.date     'flight_date'
    t.string   'flight_sub'
    t.string   'camera'
    t.string   'roll'
    t.string   'map_type'
    t.integer  'plan_only'
    t.integer  'lab_only'
    t.integer  'est_hrs_model'
    t.date     'due_date'
    t.integer  'edge_job_id'
    t.integer  'custom_trans'
    t.integer  'comp_inhouse'
    t.date     'delivered_date'
    t.integer  'done'
    t.date     'control_in'
    t.string   'control_status'
    t.date     'at_date'
    t.string   'control_results'
    t.integer  'control_check'
    t.string   'scan_staff'
    t.date     'scan_date'
    t.integer  'scan_check'
    t.string   'comp_staff'
    t.date     'comp_date'
    t.integer  'comp_check'
    t.string   'comp_sub'
    t.date     'comp_sub_due_date'
    t.integer  'comp_sub_rec'
    t.string   'img_staff'
    t.date     'img_date'
    t.integer  'img_check'
    t.string   'edit_staff'
    t.date     'edit_date'
    t.integer  'edit_check'
    t.text     'notes'
    t.string   'file1'
    t.string   'file2'
    t.string   'file3'
    t.string   'file4'
    t.string   'file5'
    t.string   'add_files'
    t.datetime 'created_at'
    t.datetime 'updated_at'
    t.integer  'flown'
    t.integer  'cust_trans'
    t.integer  'delivered'
    t.string   'at_staff'
    t.integer  'at_check'
    t.integer  'opportunity_id'
  end
```

**Update:**Adding opportunity client model/schema

**Opportunity Model:**

```
class Opportunity < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :employee
  has_one :user
  has_many :film_specs
  has_many :digital_specs
  has_many :film_quotes
  has_many :cost_proposals
  has_many :jobs

  validates :opp_status_id, presence: true
end
```

**Opportunity Schema:**

```
  create_table 'opportunities', force: true do |t|
    t.integer  'employee_id'
    t.integer  'emp2_id'
    t.integer  'emp3_id'
    t.string   'name'
    t.datetime 'prop_date'
    t.integer  'opp_status_id'
    t.string   'delay'
    t.date     'con_signed'
    t.integer  'quote_won_id'
    t.float    'total_cost'
    t.date     'exp_close'
    t.integer  'pri_comp_id'
    t.text     'notes'
    t.datetime 'created_at'
    t.datetime 'updated_at'
    t.string   'lost'
    t.string   'won'
    t.string   'location'
    t.integer  'pm_id'
    t.integer  'job_id'
  end
```

**Client Model:**

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :logo, LogoUploader
  has_many :offices
  has_many :employees, through: :offices
  has_one :office_type
  validates :name, uniqueness: { message: 'That company already exists' }

  def self.master_company
    find_by(type_id: 1)
  end

  def self.company_name(comp_id)
    find_by(id: comp_id).name
  end
end
```

**Client schema:**

```
  create_table 'companies', force: true do |t|
    t.string   'name'
    t.string   'website'
    t.string   'logo'
    t.datetime 'created_at'
    t.datetime 'updated_at'
    t.integer  'type_id'
  end
```

Comment: Assuming you commented out the code that breaks (`@job.opportunities.employee.office.client_num`), your issue is that you're calling `.employee` on an ActiveRecord collection (`@job.opportunities`) so ask yourself: what are you trying to display here? Also, you should update your question and remove all the code except what's actually broken - `_form.html.erb`

Comment: @mmichael that's an answer, not a comment.

Comment: Can you also share your opportunities and client models/ schemas? It looks like there are probably some multiple or complex associations happening. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

Comment: @inveterateliterate I have updated the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that you're calling `.employee` on an ActiveRecord collection (`@job.opportunities`). It looks like you're trying to display the client number using `@job.opportunities.employee.office.client_num` which will never work since you would first need to select a single opportunity record to get its employee. You should revisit how your `Job` and `Office` models are associated.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I took this project over a few weeks ago and have been redoing it since, when I came across this problem I thought it would be smart to reach out to Rails developers with more experience than I have. Thanks again.